Convergence of series using uniform continuity
Let $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow R$ be uniformly continuous. Prove that infinite series : $\sum\frac{1}{n}(f(n)-2f(n+1)+f(n+2))$ is convergent.
I saw some behaviour of this sum, and that for some first arguemnts it goes like:
$f(1)-\frac{3}{2}f(2)+\frac{1}{3}f(3)+\frac{1}{12}(4)+\frac{1}{30}f(5)...$
I checked some more arguments and it'll always be $\frac{1}{something}$. Other than first two and last two components. Also for n>4 it'll be smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2}f(n).$ So our sum will be smaller than $\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2}f(n))$
plus some first finite components. How I can approach this from now, and make it more mathematically rigorous.

I did not check the calculation which leads to your formula for $S_n$, but - assuming that this is correct -- try $f(x) =  \sin(ax) $ for some suitably chosen constant $a$ to get an oscillating (not converging) sequence. (Did you miss to mention a condition like convergence of $f$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$)?

I would double check the partial sums formula you got...

Oh I missed another thing, there is 1/n multiplication under sum

then you should correct the body of your question.

Let $g(n)=f(n)-f(n+1)$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for $\epsilon=1$ there is $\delta>0$ such that as long as $|x-y|\le \delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \epsilon=1$.
Let $m$ be an integer such that $m\delta<1$ but $m\delta\ge 1$. Then
$$
|f(n)-f(n+m\delta)|=|(f(n)-f(n+\delta))+(f(n+\delta)-f(n+2\delta))+
\dots +(f(n+(m-1)\delta)-f(n+m\delta))|\le m
$$
On the other hand, $|n+m\delta -(n+1)|\le \delta$ by the definition of $m$, hence
$$
|f(n+m\delta)-f(n+1)|\le 1 \quad\Longrightarrow |g(n)|=|f(n+1)-f(n)|\le m+1.
$$
Now your sum is
$$
\sum_n \frac{g(n)-g(n+1)}{n}=const+\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{g(n)}{n(n-1)}
$$
and the latter sume converges as $|g(n)|\le m+1$ is uniformly bounded and $\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$ converges.
